# Cpu overheating while playing video games

Tags: hard-drive, cpu, gaming, cpu-cores, cpu-temperature

My PC  specs are

. I3 G3260  PROCESSOR 
. INTEL 4600 HD GRAPHICS
. 4GB RAM STORAGE

This is not a monster configuration for gaming but I can easily run games like Tf2 and Witcher 1 on this device without much trouble . However recently while gaming the core temperature reaches around 80 - 90 Celsius and the cpu clock is at max frequency an occasionally the hard disk also show 100 % usage . So what happened ? I could play this games easily earlier but now it's impossible . I tried to clean the fan and also checked for corrupted drivers and fixed them but still it's not working . What should I do now ?

Comment: Specs make me think your pc is quite old. Check by hand if fans rotate easily, with almost no force applied. [Lubricate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPyHBH3WwBM) them if they don't rotate at least once when stop pushing. Might also want to replace thermal paste. Most services will do that alongside the dust cleaning for ~15$ for all.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot add a comment yet (due reputation) but when you say "earlier" and "now" what is the time difference? If it's 1-2 months, then you should consider that it's summer time and maybe your question then relates to [Why do my laptop heats up so much during the daytime?](https://superuser.com/questions/1559552/why-do-my-laptop-heats-up-so-much-during-the-daytime/1560262#1560262)