# Why do my laptop heats up so much during the daytime?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cooling, overheating

Today I noticed that [my laptop](https://www.amazon.in/iBall-CompBook-M500-Integrated-Graphics/dp/B07DJLDPF1) which I have bought for the sake of reading PDF files and some typing in MS Word heats up during daytime too much. While, the heating issue seems to disappear up to a great extent during night, it's quite unbearable to touch during day. The temperature currently at my place during daytime is 34-36 degree centigrade.

*What according to you is causing this issue which apparently appears only during daytime? Is there something I should try in order to prevent this from happening?*

Comment: Does Ctrl-Alt-Del>Task Manager show anything using much CPU?

Comment: I posted an almost similar question a few months ago (can't find the link right now, sorry), because my own laptop (2011 Lenovo ThinkPad Edge 15 with an Intel Pentium P6100 CPU) was also getting hotter in the morning, but seemed to cool down in the afternoon and was quite OK at night, temp-wise. I never got a clear answer, but I think Windows performs some maintenance tasks as soon as your PC is started or woken up, and once those maintenance tasks are done, CPU activity decreases, and with it, its temperature. I have Windows Server and Win10 on the same PC, and it happens only with Win10.

Comment: Possibly stupid question but: is your laptop in an area where it is under direct sunlight?

Comment: @gmatht, Sorry, I didn't check CPU  activity during daytime. But, it's not using much of the CPU right now, during night. Just ~10%

Comment: @Mokubai, no it is never kept under direct sun :(

Comment: Hello @Didier, does that imply that if I turn on my laptop only during night, it'll still heat up equally due to those maintenance tasks?

Comment: What's the ambient temperature at night? Ambient temperature has a profound impact on a system's ability to cool itself properly, and 35 C is hot enough of an environment that the system likely just isn't able to cool itself properly.

Comment: Maintenance tasks are set to be performed at a certain time every day, week, month, etc... depending on the task we're talking about. For example, since your PC has an SSD, there's bound to be an optimization task set to be performed every month or so. If your overheating issue happens every day, you can pretty much ignore this one, but there are others, like .NET optimization, TIWorker installing or reinstalling software in the background, etc...

Comment: Yeah @SamForbis, I too think that might be one cause, the ambient temperature right now is around ~28 degree centigrade compared to ~35 degrees during daytime.

Comment: @Didier, So, is there a way I can make those tasks run during night time?

Comment: @Sanu_012: Yes, you can change the date and time when those tasks are performed. Press the Windows and X keys together, and go to Computer Management. Under Task Scheduler, you have access to the whole task scheduling library. Find the tasks you want to edit, double-click on them, and change the settings as desired, then confirm and restart your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters it's hotter during the daytime because of the heat of the sun...

To mitigate this I would simply use a heat-conductive material (conductive as in to draw out i.e to absorb). I recommend an oven tray because it is of the right size, shape, and material. This of course is not a solution, just something that can help out.

Comment: And where will the heat conducted through that plate will go? Won't sucking heat that way cause the laptop to heat up even more. Sorry to say, but whatever thermodynamics I have studied, this will simply not work :(

Comment: If you use an aluminum tray, it should be OK, because aluminum is a very good heat-conducting material. I put mine on a breakfast plastic tray, slightly elevated on the rear, so that the airflow under the PC is constant and unobstructed. It does the trick. Keeping your PC on your lap is not good, because body heat is passed on to the PC.

Comment: I keep the laptop always on table. Is keeping an conducting tray absolutely necessary?

Comment: Along with monitoring running processes I would also ensure the laptop itself is clean i.e. vents are clear. Crack the case and clean the fan blades with compressed air and a clean (tooth)brush - you will be _amazed_ at the crap that accumulates inside. Also consider power management - select a lower plan like powersave if you don't need the performance - good for long laptop life.

Answer (score 0):

@user2901512 is right: there are big ambient temperature differences between day and night, which explain your observation.

Nowadays there are laptop tables which have extra ventilation, I'm posting a picture for the one I'm using and you can find it quite cheap on internet.
[My Laptop Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjXg6.png)

Also you can use Sysinternals' Process Explorer (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to track down the most CPU consuming tasks: usually in Windows 10 I suspect one or two svchost (but they are many). Sort by "CPU Time", double click on the most consuming one, select the Service tab and then check which of them you don't need (you can disable those from "services.msc").
[Process Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp514.png)

*Edit:*

about disabling services there are many internet articles which tells which are safe to be disabled. And I would say this is a trial and error process and it's wise first to make a system restore point (from Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System > System Protection > Create...)

- Here's one link: https://www.pcerror-fix.com/windows-10-services-to-disable-for-gaming
- and here's almost the full list of the ones I have disabled: [my disabled services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCuSh.png), but also many others which I needed only "on-demand" I changed them from Automatic to Manual.

Comment: Won't disabling those processes hamper performance of the laptop?

Comment: Disabling services is a slow process and require many tries till you get it well done. Also many services which you don't need to be run all the time change them from Automatic to Manual. Ensure you have a system restore point before each major iteration so that you can revert (https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-system-restore-windows-10)